# Prove : $\frac{SA}{SA'}+\frac{SC}{SC'}=\frac{SB}{SB'}+\frac{SD}{SD'}$

Tags: geometry

The parallelogram $ABCD$.

> Prove : $\frac{SA}{SA'}+\frac{SC}{SC'}=\frac{SB}{SB'}+\frac{SD}{SD'}$

Thanks :)

P/s : I have no ideas about this problem !! :(

[image]

Comment: You should explain the construction of the diagram, instead of making others guess at the intentions.

Comment: What is the line d?

Comment: @rah4927: my guess is that line $d$ is an unspecified line that could appear anywhere, similar to the point $S$, and the only specific info we have is that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram...

Comment: Actually, I'm not good of English, so that I draw a picture instead , I'm very sorry !! :(

Comment: @abiessu : you right, but the point $S$ is outside the parallelogram $ABCD$ !

Comment: @LêTấnKhang It is not required that $S$ is outside of the parallelogram. Statement would still be true, using signed distances. The advantage of being outside would only be to avoid talking about signed distances in the statement.

Comment: @abiessu Well, you want to avoid the limiting cases where some lines are parallel, but otherwise $X'$ is the (unique) intersection of $d$ and $SX$ (suitably extended). As mentioned, this could be avoided if the construction was clearly stated.

Comment: @CalvinLin: yes, I see that now

Comment: @abiessu : why the line $d$ don't pass through $SA,SB,SC,SD$ ??

Comment: @LêTấnKhang: for a moment, I thought that it would not pass through all four lines if $S$ were inside $ABCD$, but except for the case where $d$ is parallel to any of those four lines, $d$ will intersect with each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $\frac{ [SA'C']}{A'C'} = \frac{[SB'D']} { B'D'} $.

**Hint:** It is equivalent to show that $ \frac{ [SAC'] + [SCA'] } { A'C'} = \frac{ [SBD'] + [SDB'] } { B'D'} $.

**Hint:** It is equivalent to show that the (signed) distance that $A$ and $C$ are from the line, is equal to the (signed) distance that $B$ and $D$ are from the straight line $d$.

**Hint:** It is equivalent that $\vec{OA} + \vec{OC} = \vec{OB} + \vec{OD} $. This is obvious for a parallelogram, as both sides are equal to $2 \vec {OE}$ where $E$ is the center of the parallelogram.

Comment: Is $[SA'C']$ an angle measure, or a triangle measure of area or something similar?

Comment: @abiessu Area of figure. It's a 'standard notation' that isn't so standard.

Comment: @CalvinLin I just have this question: Is it right to say that since A' , B' , C' and D' are collinear, that their cross ratio must be -1 in order for the OP's assertion to be true? I recognize some Projective Geometry in this picture, but couldn't come up with a Theorem regarding the rays SA, SB, SC and SD and their respective ratio's.

Comment: @imranfat In the construction of the problem, (I believe that) you start out with a given point $S$ AND a given line $d$, and proceed to construct $X'$. So yes, your statement is true, and follows as a corollary of the construction.